# Scrubbing a block from a call to super

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-attr

I'm working with ActiveAttr which gives you that nice initialize via block option:

```
person = Person.new() do |p|
  p.first_name = 'test'
  p.last_name = 'man'
end
```

However, in a specific class that include ActiveAttr::Model, I want to bypass this functionality since I want to use the block for something else. So here we go:

```
class Imperator::Command
 include ActiveAttr::Model
end


class MyCommand < Imperator::Command

  def initialize(*args, &block)
    @my_block = block

    super(*args)
  end
end
```

This fails miserably, because the block still gets passed up the chain, and eventually inside of ActiveAttr, this code gets run:

```
def initialize(*)
  super
  yield self if block_given?
end
```

So if my call looks like so:

```
MyCommand.new() { |date| date.advance(month: 1) }
```

it fails as follows:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `advance' for #<MyCommand:0x007fe432c4fb80>
```

since MyCommand has no method :advance it the call to MyCommand obviously fails.

So my question is this, is there a way that I can remove the block from the method signature before I call `super` again, so that the block travels no further than my overridden initializer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
super(*args,&nil)
```

The & makes ruby use nil as the block and ruby seems smart enough to realise this means no block.

Comment: Perfect, I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: This must be a ruby bug, although it is still present in ruby 2.0

Answer (score 0):

That is certainly a neat trick, but a better approach would be to not use ActiveAttr::Model module directly and instead include only the modules you need.

Rather than

```
class Imperator::Command
  include ActiveAttr::Model
end
```

Do

```
class Imperator::Command
  include BasicModel
  # include BlockInitialization
  include Logger
  include MassAssignmentSecurity
  include AttributeDefaults
  include QueryAttributes
  include TypecastedAttributes

  def initialize(*args, &block)
    @my_block = block
    super(*args)
  end
end
```

Once you see the exploded view of ActiveAttr::Model is doing there may be other things you really don't want.  In that case just simply omit the includes.  The intention was to provide an à la carte approach to model constructing.